# Nodejs Connect with SQL not connecting

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, mean-stack, node-modules

I am trying to connect to MS SQL DB using Node JS But I am getting the following error.

> { ConnectionError: Login failed for user 'Gurpanth'.
>       at ConnectionError not connected

```
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();

    /* GET home page. */
    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
        GetData(function (recordSet) {
            res.render('index', {product: recordSet})
        });
    });

    var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;

    var config = {
        userName: "Gurpanth",
        password: "windowspassword",
        server: "GURPANTH",
        options: {
            database: "NodeJSDb",
            encrypt: true,
        }
    };

    var connection = new Connection (config);

    connection.on('connect', function(err){
        console.log(err);
        if(err!=null){
            console.log("not connected");
        }
        else{
            console.log("Connected")
            connection.close();
        };
    });
    module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message you gave indicates that your username and/or password are not correct. Does that user exist in SQL Server?